# How can i write a workbook content in a loop into the same excel file

Tags: java, excel, for-loop, apache-poi

i'm trying to add workbook content to fos in every loop but i'm getting an error org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException , if i write workbook outside the loop it writes only the last workbook in my loop. any solution? Here is my code, thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException, ParseException  {

    String [] listefichiers;
    String chemin="D:\\part";

    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("D:\\saisonedit3.xlsx");
    FichierExcel fG_gares=new FichierExcel("D:\\Traitement aristote\\","Parametres_MP_java.xlsx","Gares");

    File repertoire = new File(chemin);
    listefichiers=repertoire.list();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook=null; 

    for(int i=0;i<listefichiers.length;i++){

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(chemin+"\\"+listefichiers[i]);

    System.out.println("nom fic "+listefichiers[i]);

    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    workbook.write(fos);    
    }


   fos.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: You are thinking, you could simply write multiple Excel workbook files into one Excel workbook file? No, you can't. You must getting the content of each single source workbook file and then putting that content into the target workbook. While doing so, you must determine how the content shall be inputted into the target workbook: As additional sheets - or into existing sheets and if so where in those sheets.

Comment: @AxelRichter Richter , do you have a code example for this ? i always used write method to write single workbook into an excel wokbook. i dont' know how to do so in a loop.

Comment: That's not trivial. You need a target workbook, at first empty. Then in the main loop you are opening the first source workbook. There loop through all sheets. For each source sheet, create a sheet in the target workbook and copy all data from source sheet to target sheet. So on for all further source workbooks. At last you are writing the target workbook.